# What's the best way to add an alert box to a link in D7

Tags: navigation

I have a link, which is rendered via the l function. It's a link which calls a function that deletes a node. Before the function is called, I want an alert box to pop up and give the user the option to 'Cancel' or 'Confirm'. Adding this as an argument to the l function works:

```
array('attributes' => array('onclick' => 'return confirm("Are you sure?")'))
```

...but is there an existing function, or something, that does a nicer job?

I'd rather not add a contrib module for such a small task.

Answer (score 1):

no there is no js related function in drupal 7 that provides a functionality like that. just make sure that custom setup you have there is in your template.php

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in functions for client-side JS UI confirmation prompts.

If you're want to rely on just Drupal core for node deletion prompts you can use the built-in deletion forms (assuming the user has permissions to access it) and use the `destination` query parameter to redirect the user back to where they need to be:

```
$nid = 123;
$return_path = 'admin';
l(t('Remove Node'), 'node/' . $nid . '/delete', ['query' => ['destination' => $return_path]]);
```